# How to plot chron times in hh:mm?

Tags: r, datetime, time, chron

I'm tring to plot Time as `hh:min` or `hh:min:ss`. But as I'm using chron package (it restores time values as a fraction of a day), ggplot don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type times, so it uses continuous to plot the data. Some sample of the data:

```
> x$Time
 [1] 00:00:00 00:15:00 00:30:00 00:45:00 01:00:00 01:15:00 01:30:00 01:45:00 02:00:00
[10] 02:15:00 02:30:00 02:45:00 03:00:00 03:15:00 03:30:00 03:45:00 04:00:00 04:15:00

> x$Total
 [1]    1    4    0    0    4    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[17]    0    0    0    0    2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    2    0    7    9
[33]   27   87  143  251 1263 1797 2074 2171   16 2542 2924 3194 3185 3274 3282 3362

ggplot(aes(x = x$Hora, y = x$Sum_C.Total), data = x) + geom_point()
```

This gives a graph where Y axis works, but X axis are values from 0 to 1 (as all my time data are from `00:00:00` to `24:00:00`). How can I convert this fraction of a day in time values in order that ggplot can plot it as `hh:mm:ss` or `hh:mm`?

PS: I tried this solution ([plot chron times as hours from origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34114890/plot-chron-times-as-hours-from-origin)) but it doesn't allow me to use the `"%02d:00"` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the following is what you want. if it isn't, just say so and I will delete this answer.

First read in your `Time` vector and make up some `Total`.

```
Time <- scan(what = character(), text = 
"00:00:00 00:15:00 00:30:00 00:45:00 01:00:00 01:15:00 01:30:00 01:45:00 02:00:00
02:15:00 02:30:00 02:45:00 03:00:00 03:15:00 03:30:00 03:45:00 04:00:00 04:15:00")

set.seed(1)
Total <- cumsum(rnorm(length(Time)))
```

Now for the graph. I will create a `data.frame` with a column of class `"times"` and then make it shorter, without the seconds, for the plot.

```
library(chron)

Time <- chron(times. = Time)
x <- data.frame(Hora = Time, Sum_C.Total = Total)

Hr <- sub(":00$", "", as.character(x$Hora))

ggplot(data = cbind(x, Hr), aes(x = Hr, y = Sum_C.Total)) +
    geom_point()
```

On my screen monitor I had to maximize the graphics window in order for the x axis labels not to superimpose.